# How does a website know it's you for automatic login?

Tags: cookies

When you visit gmail, for example, how does it know it's you and automatically log you in, taking you straight to your inbox?

How does it protect against fraudulent activity (say, somebody faking your MAC address, etc.) ? If cookies is the answer, what protects against somebody copying that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is cookies!
They'll have the Secure and HttpOnly flags so they're only communicated over HTTPS and can't be intercepted.
The browser will only send them to the domain they're issued by.

If the browser or your computer is compromised then you might have a problem, but they could just get your passwords rather than fiddling around copying cookies.

see
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag